# Tasks.await not working for FirebaseStorage

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am downloading multiple files using FirebaseStorage. The task to download the files is inside a WHILE loop. The WHILE loop is inside another FOR loop. The problem is that I want the WHILE loop to move forward only when all downloads are complete. I tried using Tasks.await(task) but it doesn't seem to work. Could you guys help me with that?

```
For (DataSnapshot ds: datasnapshot.getChildren()){
    ...
    while (i[0] < imgs.length) {
        Task<Uri> task = mStorageReference.child(uid).child("notes").child(imgname).getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    ...
                });
        try {
             Tasks.await(task);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        i[0]++;
        }
    }
```

I also tried using i[0]++ inside the storage task, but the loop just freezes.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Task.await()` on Android is a recipe for problems, as even if it works, it will actually block the main thread. Are you sure you're not looking for `Task.whenAllComplete()`, which returns a `Task` that completes when all `getDownloadUrl` tasks complete.

Implementing it would look something like this:

```
List<Task<Uri>> downloadUrlTasks = new LinkedList<Task<Uri>>();

while (i[0] < imgs.length) {
    Task<Uri> task = mStorageReference.child(uid).child("notes").child(imgname).getDownloadUrl();
    downloadUrlTasks.add(task);
    i[0]++;
}

try {
     Tasks.whenAllComplete(downloadUrlTasks).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<List<Task<Uri>>() {
         @Override
         public void onComplete(@NonNull List<Task<Uri>> tasks) {
             // All tasks have completed, now you can get all download URLs by looping over the tasks
         }
     });
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Even simpler: if you only want to process the download URLs if all of them were successfully gotten from the server, you can use `Tasks. whenAllSuccess`:

```
 Tasks.whenAllSuccess(downloadUrlTasks).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Uri>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(@NonNull List<Uri> uris) {
         // All tasks have succeeded, the uris list contains all download URLs
     }
 });
```